# How can size_type be an unsigned integral if npos is -1?

Tags: c++, string, stl, size-t, size-type

If the `std::size_type` of a `std::string` is that of the default allocator,

> **21.3.1 Class template basic_string**
>    `typedef typename allocator_traits<Allocator>::size_type size_type;`

And the `std::size_type` for the default allocator is that of `std::size_t`,

> **20.9.9 The default allocator**
>   `typedef size_t size_type;`

And we know that `std::size_t` is always an unsigned integer type,

> *C++ Standard*
>   **5.3.3 Sizeof**
>   The result of sizeof and sizeof... is a constant of type `std::size_t`.
>   [ Note: std::size_t is defined in the standard header `<cstddef>`
>
> **8.2 Types**
>   The contents are the same as the Standard C library header `<stddef.h>`, with the following changes:

---

> *C Standard*
>   **6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators**
>   The value of the result of both operators is implementation-defined,
>   and its type (an unsigned integer type) is `size_t`, defined in
>   `<stddef.h>` (and other headers).

How can [std::basic_string::npos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) (defined as a `size_type`) be -1?

Comment: It's `-1` implicitly converted to `size_type`?

Comment: Did you actually read the page you linked? There the first sentence says "This is a special value equal to the maximum value representable by the type size_type."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ spec requires that signed types can be converted to unsigned types. §4.7/2 states that

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source
>   integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type)

This means that the C++ spec guarantees that -1 can be converted to a `size_type` even if `size_type` is unsigned, and the result will be equal to the largest possible `size_type` because adding 1 to that number needs to give back 0.

Comment: So in other words if it were 2 bytes it would be 0xFFFF

Answer (score 2):

The definition uses the fact that unsigned integers follow modular arithmetic, and `-1` converts to the largest unsigned integer of a given type.

Comment: Ok, make sense.  I didn't think you could construct unsigned integrals with negative numbers and rely on an underflow like that.